# Jquery Recursion function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I m new to Jquery... I m developing an application using ruby on rails. Here what i have to do is I m calling a controller action from Jquery and displaying its output in a div with typewriter effect. Now i want to display a button "play" on clicking which tyewriter effect for content starts and "play" button changes to "stop". And on stopping it, it converts to "play" and start playing and so on. For this i have used this code on Jquery..

```
var text="content of text here";
var delay=50;
var currentChar=1;
var destination="[not defined]";

function set_file(id,time,user,node,activity) 
{
       var filename = "";
       filename = user+"_"+node+"_"+activity+"_"+time;

       jQuery("#play_"+id).click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       jQuery("#img_"+id).attr('src',"/images/stop_images.png");
       jQuery("#img_"+id).attr('title',"Stop");
       jQuery(this).attr('id','stop_'+id);
       jQuery.get('/requests/download_log/?filename=' + filename, function(data) {
       startTyping(data, 50, "request_"+id);
       });
      jQuery("#stop_"+id).click(function(){
            jQuery("#img_"+id).attr('src',"/images/play_images.png");
            jQuery("#img_"+id).attr('title',"Play");
                    text="content of text here";
                    delay=50;
                    currentChar=1;
                    destination="[not defined]";
            });
  }

 function startTyping(textParam, delayParam, destinationParam)
 {
      text=textParam;
      delay=delayParam;
       currentChar=1;
    destination=destinationParam;
    type();
   }
 function type()
 {
  if (document.getElementById)
 {
   var dest=document.getElementById(destination);
  if (dest)
  {
  dest.innerHTML=text.substr(0, currentChar);
  currentChar++
    if(currentChar <= text.length)
     {
            setTimeout("type()", delay);
      }
  }
  }
 }
```

My view page is

```
<% i = 1%>
 <%=link_to_function result.time,:id => "log_#{i}",:onclick => "set_file(#{i},'#{time_val}','#{result.user}','#{result.nodeip}','#{result.activityuser}')" %>
<div id = "file_<%= i %>" class = "file">
<%= link_to_function image_tag("play_images.png",:width => 30, :height => 30,:align => 'left', :title => 'Play', :id => "img_#{i}"),:id => "play_#{i}"%>
<b><h7 id= "fname_<%= i %>" class = "h7">""</h7></b>
<%= link_to_function image_tag("images.jpeg",:align => 'right'), :id => "close_#{i}"%>
<div id = "request_<%= i%>" class = "request">
</div>
</div>
<%i = i + 1%>
```

Please anybody tell me how can i accomplish it, how can i stop typewriter mode?

Comment: There are just too many questions you're asking here. Try to track down your problems to the bare essential and post separate questions if needed.

Comment: Ok then tell me is there any way to know the id of clicked element. If it is possible then i can easily track whether the clicked element's id is "stop" or "play" then i can define corresponding action.

Comment: If you want to improve your question please [edit] it.